Chart JS Curved Labels in Polar Area
I am working on a web project using Chart.js to create a PolarArea chart that dynamically updates based on the selected class from a dropdown menu. I have encountered an issue where the labels are dynamic, but I need it to be static
const subjects = {
    5: ["Укр. мова", "Укр. літ.", "Заруб. літ.", "Англ. мова", "Історія", "Математика", "Природа", "ІТ", "Фізкультура", "Мистецтво"],
    6: ["Укр. мова", "Укр. літ.", "Заруб. літ.", "Англ. мова", "Історія", "Математика", "Природа", "ІТ", "Географія", "Фізкультура", "Мистецтво"],
    7: ["Укр. мова", "Укр. літ.", "Заруб. літ.", "Англ. мова", "Всесвіт. історія", "Історія Укр.", "Алгебра", "Геометрія", "ІТ", "Біологія", "Географія", "Фізика", "Хімія", "Здоров'я", "Мистецтво", "Фізкультура"],
    8: ["Укр. мова", "Укр. літ.", "Заруб. літ.", "Англ. мова", "Всесвіт. історія", "Історія Укр.", "Алгебра", "Геометрія", "ІТ", "Біологія", "Географія", "Фізика", "Хімія", "Здоров'я", "Мистецтво", "Фізкультура"],
    9: ["Укр. мова", "Укр. літ.", "Заруб. літ.", "Англ. мова", "Всесвіт. історія", "Історія Укр.", "Алгебра", "Геометрія", "ІТ", "Біологія", "Географія", "Фізика", "Хімія", "Здоров'я", "Мистецтво", "Фізкультура"],
    10: ["Укр. мова", "Укр. літ.", "Заруб. літ.", "Англ. мова", "Всесвіт. історія", "Історія Укр.", "Алгебра", "Геометрія", "ІТ", "Біологія", "Географія", "Фізика", "Хімія", "Здоров'я", "Мистецтво", "Фізкультура"],
    11: ["Укр. мова", "Укр. літ.", "Заруб. літ.", "Англ. мова", "Всесвіт. історія", "Історія Укр.", "Алгебра", "Геометрія", "ІТ", "Біологія", "Географія", "Фізика", "Хімія", "Здоров'я", "Мистецтво", "Фізкультура"]
};


const data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: [],
        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.7)',
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
};

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'polarArea',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        
        layout: {
            padding: {
                top: 30,
                bottom: 30,
                left: 30,
                right: 30
            }
        },
        scales: {
            r: {
                min: 1, // мінімальне значення
                max: 12,
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 1, 
                    color: '#000', // колір поділок
                    backdropColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)', // фон під поділками
                    font: {
                        size: 14 // розмір шрифту для поділок
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    color: '#888', // колір сітки
                    circular: true
                },
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            labels: {
                size: 1,
                render: 'label',
                arc: true,
                fontColor: '#000',
                position: 'outside'
            }
        }
    }
});

I've tied everything, but nothing works

Please try to explain what you are trying to do and what is the actual problem you encountered.  Rather than trying to describe the issues in words, better add your code -- for instance, how do you use the subjects object to populate the datasets

To make the labels of the PolarArea chart static, you should modify the data.labels array to include the labels you want to remain unchanged, regardless of the selected class from the dropdown menu.
Here’s how you can adjust your code to keep the labels static while still allowing the data to update dynamically:
Set the labels outside the dropdown menu change event so they remain constant.
Update only the data property of the chart when a different class is selected.
const subjects = {
    5: [5, 8, 3, 4, 7, 6, 9, 2, 5, 3], // Example data for each subject
    6: [6, 7, 5, 8, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6],
    7: [8, 9, 4, 6, 7, 5, 3, 4, 8, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 6],
    8: [7, 6, 5, 8, 9, 4, 6, 7, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4, 6, 5],
    9: [9, 6, 8, 7, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 4],
    10: [5, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 6, 7, 5, 8, 6, 7, 4, 6],
    11: [6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4, 3, 6, 7, 5, 9, 8, 6, 7, 4]
};

// Static labels
const staticLabels = ["Укр. мова", "Укр. літ.", "Заруб. літ.", "Англ. мова", "Історія", "Математика", "Природа", "ІТ", "Географія", "Фізика", "Хімія", "Фізкультура"];

const data = {
    labels: staticLabels, // Set static labels here
    datasets: [{
        data: [], // This will be updated dynamically
        backgroundColor: [], // Add custom colors if needed
        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.7)',
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
};

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'polarArea',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        layout: {
            padding: {
                top: 30,
                bottom: 30,
                left: 30,
                right: 30
            }
        },
        scales: {
            r: {
                min: 1, 
                max: 12,
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 1, 
                    color: '#000',
                    backdropColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)', 
                    font: {
                        size: 14
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    color: '#888', 
                    circular: true
                },
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    }
});

// Update chart data dynamically based on the selected class
function updateChartData(classLevel) {
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = subjects[classLevel]; // Update data only
    myChart.update(); // Re-render the chart with the new data
}

// Assuming you have a dropdown menu where you select the class level
document.getElementById('classSelect').addEventListener('change', function () {
    const selectedClass = this.value; // Get selected class
    updateChartData(selectedClass); // Call function to update chart
});

